# SSRS: Export To Excel?

Tags: reporting-services

Whenever i export my SSRS report to excel, the record gets extracted to multiple columns instead of one column which makes harder to do much stuff in excel? I know it has to do with alignment but can anyone tell me specific what i can do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to be more detailed in your question to provide a specific answer to your problem. However, in my experience, in order to achieve a useful Excel export from an SSRS report it is best to keep the layout of the report as simple as possible. Keep distinct fields in their own columns and keep merged fields and groupings to a minimum. That way your field data should be given a column of its own in Excel and allow for further manipulation with relative ease.

Comment: This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisbal/archive/2006/07/08/659545.aspx) has further detail to support SMS's answer.

Comment: @richaux - I agree. Report headers are usually the culprit. Remove them, or make them the full page width to avoid split columns below.

Comment: If you have headers above a tablix, condider inserting blank rows above the data in the tablix.  Fit the header information into these rows.  That forces the header to align to the columns in the tablix.