# Unable to sort SSRS report in Excel

Tags: sql, sorting, reporting-services, export-to-excel

I need to figure out a way to fix an issue our customers having while exporting SSRS report to Excel.  The report successfully gets exported to Excel, but is not sortable.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of what the report structure looks like in Excel (I have deleted all the data from report to upload it here).  In SSRS, I am not combining two columns or anything.  All that is done in stored proc.

Let me know if I need to include additional information!

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem with SSRS. Your header cells overlap your table columns, likely in an uneven manner, causing entire columns of your table to be merged cells between two columns.

A good solution is to add rows to the top of your table, and insert your header pieces in the table itself, so all alignment will be perfect and your table cells won't result in merging.

Comment: Note: In these header rows of your table, merging cells is acceptable and won't affect the sortability of the cells in the rows below.

Comment: Is there a way to hide the boarder for that first row so it still looks like header?

Comment: Yes. I don't have SSRS in front of me, but for all cells in your header region, you can set BorderStyle = None.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273701/ssrs-export-to-excel/2273747#2273747

Comment: [To insert a row into a selected data region.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/insert-or-delete-a-row-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16#to-insert-a-row-in-a-selected-data-region)